# Why aren't users getting in-app-purchase confirmation in Swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am presenting IAP options in an alert view, and here is the code that I use to do that:

```
paidAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Purchase", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (action) in
                IAPHandler.shared.purchaseMyProduct(index: 0)

            }))
            paidAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Restore", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (action) in
                IAPHandler.shared.restorePurchase()

            }))
            paidAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: { (action) in

            }))
```

I handle the actual IAP in another Swift file, which is posted here:

```
    import UIKit
import StoreKit

enum IAPHandlerAlertType{
    case disabled
    case restored
    case purchased

    func message() -> String{
        switch self {
        case .disabled:

            let notificationFeedbackGenerator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
            notificationFeedbackGenerator.prepare()
            notificationFeedbackGenerator.notificationOccurred(.error)

            return "Purchases are disabled on your device."
        case .restored:

            let notificationFeedbackGenerator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
            notificationFeedbackGenerator.prepare()
            notificationFeedbackGenerator.notificationOccurred(.success)

            return "Unlimited strategies have been successfully unlocked. You can restore this purchase using this Apple ID on other devices."
        case .purchased:

            let notificationFeedbackGenerator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
            notificationFeedbackGenerator.prepare()
            notificationFeedbackGenerator.notificationOccurred(.success)

            return "Unlimited strategies have been successfully unlocked. You can restore this purchase using this Apple ID on other devices."
        }
    }
}

class IAPHandler: NSObject {
    static let shared = IAPHandler()

    let NON_CONSUMABLE_PURCHASE_PRODUCT_ID = "com.isaranjha.opc.fullversion"

    fileprivate var productID = ""
    fileprivate var productsRequest = SKProductsRequest()
    fileprivate var iapProducts = [SKProduct]()

    var purchaseStatusBlock: ((IAPHandlerAlertType) -> Void)?

    // MARK: - MAKE PURCHASE OF A PRODUCT
    func canMakePurchases() -> Bool {  return SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()  }

    func purchaseMyProduct(index: Int){
        if iapProducts.count == 0 { return }

        if self.canMakePurchases() {
            let product = iapProducts[index]
            let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)

            print("PRODUCT TO PURCHASE: \(product.productIdentifier)")
            productID = product.productIdentifier
        } else {
            purchaseStatusBlock?(.disabled)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - RESTORE PURCHASE
    func restorePurchase(){
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }

    // MARK: - FETCH AVAILABLE IAP PRODUCTS
    func fetchAvailableProducts(){

        // Put here your IAP Products ID's
        let productIdentifiers = NSSet(objects: NON_CONSUMABLE_PURCHASE_PRODUCT_ID
        )

        productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers as! Set<String>)
        productsRequest.delegate = self
        productsRequest.start()
    }
}

extension IAPHandler: SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver{
    // MARK: - REQUEST IAP PRODUCTS
    func productsRequest (_ request:SKProductsRequest, didReceive response:SKProductsResponse) {

        if (response.products.count > 0) {
            iapProducts = response.products
            for product in iapProducts{
                let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
                numberFormatter.formatterBehavior = .behavior10_4
                numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
                numberFormatter.locale = product.priceLocale
                let price1Str = numberFormatter.string(from: product.price)
                print(product.localizedDescription + "\nfor just \(price1Str!)")
            }
        }
    }

    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        purchaseStatusBlock?(.restored)
    }

    // MARK:- IAP PAYMENT QUEUE
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            if let trans = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction {
                switch trans.transactionState {
                case .purchased:
                    print("purchased")
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    purchaseStatusBlock?(.purchased)
                    break

                case .failed:
                    print("failed")
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break
                case .restored:
                    print("restored")
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break

                default: break
                }}}
    }
}
```

However, multiple users (but not all users) have reported that they are able to purchase the IAP fine (it charges them and everything), but they do not get any confirmation that I have coded in (alert saying that the purchase was successful etc.) and therefore none of the purchased features. The only workaround we've been able to find is that the user needs to kill the app from multitasking, get to the initial IAP purchase alert again, but select Restore, and then it prompts accordingly and the features are unlocked.

I can't figure out where I am going wrong with this, but seeing as how Restore functionality seems to work, I'm assuming I'm missing something for actual purchasing that will call the case .purchased properly and display the alert.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have a logic error in your `.purchased` state - You should not finish the transaction until you have updated any state needed to unlock or process the purchase.  You are finishing the transaction before you call the optional `purchaseStatusBlock` - If that block is `nil` for any reason then you will finish the transaction but not actually process it.  You should use something like `if block = self.purchaseStatusBlock { block(.purchased) finishTransaction()}`

Comment: If I switch the finish transaction line to after sending back .purchased, that should work also? Thanks for the help

Comment: You need to check if the purchaseBlock isn't nil before finishing the transaction.  You might need to do some more testing to determine under what conditions that property is becoming nil

Comment: If all you're doing is implementing a single non-consumable purchase, this might help you: https://github.com/BooberBunz/In-app-purchases-on-IOS